# Android Messages can't send images

Tags: sms, google-messages

I am using "Android Messages" (until recently called "Google Messenger") for SMS on my Moto G (3rd generation).

Works fine, except for sending images. It tries (*Sending...*) for a few minutes, and eventually tells me that it was not able to send.

I cannot discover where to get support for this app. I had used Textra in the past, and never had trouble sending images.

I would appreciate help, even if the only help is letting me know how to file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

You might be having a number of APNs pre-loaded on your handset. Just keep the right APN and delete the extras. Keeping only the right APN will force the messenger to use that particular APN.

Follow this path for deleting APN.

Settings → Wireless and Network  → More   → Mobile Network → Access point names.

To find out which APN to keep refer [this](http://www.androidcentral.com/what-apn-and-how-do-i-change-it) documentation.

PS. After deleting APN, if you face network issues, you can simply reset it to default by  Settings → Wireless and Network → More → Mobile Network → Access point names → menu → Reset to default.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems a little crazy. Why should I need to change APNs when MMS worked fine for a different texting app? This seems like the sort of problem that would have prevented _any_ texting app from sending images.

Comment: Sometimes, google messenger couldn't decide which APN to use, when there are more than 1 APNs  available for sending MMS

Comment: OK, this was the opposite of helpful. I deleted an APN. Didn't help. So I reset to default. Now I can't send _*any*_ text messages. I don't even know who to contact to determine the correct ADN settings.

Comment: Update -- can now send text messages again, would reverse downvote, but locked in.

Comment: Glad to know it worked.

Comment: No, it didn't work, I still can't send images. But I can send SMS again so I'm at least no worse off.

Comment: Did you try deleting the unnecessary APNs and keeping the **Right** one? I have already mentioned the link for the [documentation](http://www.androidcentral.com/what-apn-and-how-do-i-change-it) that might help you in deciding which APN to keep:)

Comment: I tried to understand the documentation. Decided that this is absurd. Why should I need to understand APNs to use the official Google SMS app? Returned to Textra, because *it just works*.